# Resizing table in beamer for readability

Tags: tables, beamer

[image]I have inserted a table, originally from `Excel`, into a `Beamer` presentation. The table does not fit into the frame and I used `resizebox` to make it fit. This renders the table unreadable. Is there a solution to this? Here is an MWE:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
    \usetheme{Boadilla}
    \usecolortheme{dove}
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
    \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\tiny}
    \usepackage{color} 
    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{mdwmath}
    \usepackage{mdwtab}
    \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{array}
 
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
          \centering
          \caption{Resistivity of samples prepared from $ 0.5\:mg/ml $ CNT solution}
          \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tabularx}{1.8\textwidth}{ccccccccrrr}
                  &      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Resistivity on cellulose filter} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Resistivity after transferring to glass substrate} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Resistivity after baking the transferred samples} \\
            Volume of solution used for sample (ml) & Thickness (micron) & Resistance & Sheet Resistance & Resistivity (OHM cm) & Resistance & Sheet Resistance & Resistivity (OHM cm) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Resistance} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sheet Resistance} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Resistivity (OHM cm)} \\
            10    & 3.015 & 16.32860687 & 73.96858911 & 0.02230153 & 27.89651855 & 126.371229 & 0.038100926 &       &       &  \\
            20    & 6.8375 & 7.248137422 & 32.83406252 & 0.02245029 & 13.77673335 & 62.40860206 & 0.042671882 &       &      &   \\
            \end{tabularx}%
        }
          \label{conductivitymeasure}%
        \end{table}%

\end{frame}     
\end{document}
```

Comment: First, your code is incomplete. It's missing at least a `document` environment and a `frame` environment. Also, two questions to help build an answer: would you be fine with 1) vertically written text ? 2) less digits in the numerical values?

Comment: never use rsizebox on tables, it will never produce a good outcome. Also `tabularx`  always needs at least one `X` column or it can not adjust the table to the desired width.

Comment: My bad, I forgot the document and frame commands in this example that I posted. They are there in my original tex file and it compiles successfully. I considered the option of vertical text but that defeats the purpose of the presentation. I would use it as a last resort. I would like to have the digits if possible but otherwise it is alright to have less.

Comment: No problem, please notice that you can edit your original post to add the missing lines in the code.

Comment: Ummm, is it absolutely necessary to show 8 decimal digits of precision? Will 2 or 3 digits maybe do just as well? Please advise.

Comment: Agreed. I'd almost say that it can't be necessary, because I have hard time getting how macroscopic physics can have statistically significant digits almost down to the microscopic scale. I'm curious too.

Comment: @Mico I do not require such precision. Can you provide a solution considering that only 2 significant figures are enough?

Comment: @AniruddhaGhosh - Please see the answer I posted a minute ago.

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs *a lot* of corrections and other adjustments in order to typeset a decent-looking table. Some sugggestions, in no particular order.

- Please start your code with `\documentclass`, not with `\begin{document}`, and please make sure to load all packages *before* executing `\begin{document}`. (I just noticed that user @Miyase has applied the required corrections to your code in the meantime.)
- The `beamer` document class doesn't have "floats"; the `table` and `figure` overhead is ignored. I'd therefore get rid of the `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` directives and replace `\caption{...}` with `\frametitle{...}`.
- Don't ever use `\resizebox` on tabular material unless you want to run the very real risk of rendering the material virtually unreadable.
- The whole point of using a `tabularx` environment is to allow automating in some (or possibly even all) columns. But your code then employs the `c` and `r` column types, which do not allow automatic line breaking. Since you set up a variant of the `X` column type in the preamble of your document, why not use it?
- It's essential to allow linebreaking in the header cells of all 11 columns. Also, be sure not to use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` on any headers, as doing so will once again suppress automatic line breaking.
- Don't even think about displaying numbers with 8 and 9 decimal digits, especially if there are 9 or 10 such data columns. I suggest you load the `siunitx` package and employ its `S` column type to apply automatic rounding to either 2 or 3 decimal digits; see the code below for an implementation of this idea.
- Do use the `\unit` and `\qty` macros of the `siunitx` package to typeset scientific units and quantity/unit combinations. And do please "micron" with `\unit{\micro\meter}`.

With these adjustments in place, you'll get the following "look":

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

%% new:
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}C@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X} % centered version of "X" type
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep\relax}C}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\usepackage{siunitx} % for S col. type and \unit and \qty macros
 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,round-mode=places}
\frametitle{Resistivity of samples prepared from 
     \qty{0.5}{\milli\gram\per\milli\liter} CNT solution}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{@{} C S[table-format=3.2,round-precision=2]
          *{3}{S[table-format=3.2,round-precision=2] 
               S[table-format=3.2,round-precision=2] 
               S[table-format=1.3,round-precision=3]} @{}}
\toprule
\mytab{Volume used for sample (\unit{\milli\liter})}
& {\mytab{Thickness (\unit{\micro\meter})}}
& \multicolumn{3}{Z}{%
     Resistivity on cellulose filter} 
& \multicolumn{3}{Z}{%
     Resistivity after transferring to glass substrate}
& \multicolumn{3}{Z@{}}{%
     Resistivity after baking the transferred samples}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-8} \cmidrule(l){9-11} 
&  
& \mC{Resistance} & \mC{Sheet Resistance} & \mC{Resistivity (\unit{\ohm\centi\meter})} 
& \mC{Resistance} & \mC{Sheet Resistance} & \mC{Resistivity (\unit{\ohm\centi\meter})} 
& \mC{Resistance} & \mC{Sheet Resistance} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{Resistivity (\unit{\ohm\centi\meter})} \\
\midrule
10    & 3.015 & 16.32860687 & 73.96858911 & 0.02230153 & 27.89651855 & 126.371229 & 0.038100926 &       &       &  \\
20    & 6.8375 & 7.248137422 & 32.83406252 & 0.02245029 & 13.77673335 & 62.40860206 & 0.042671882 &       &      &   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This code for some reason doesn't compile. I get the error - Undefined control sequence. \end{frame} for some reason.

Comment: @AniruddhaGhosh - Are you sure that `\end{frame}` is triggering the error message? Please state the exact error message you get. For sure, the code I posted compiles without errors on my system (TeXLive2022, all updates installed). Incidentally, which TeX distribution do you employ, and when did you last update it?

Comment: sorry for the delay in responding. I am including an image of the error in my original quesetion.

Comment: @AniruddhaGhosh - Please answer my earlier question: Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when did you last update it?

Comment: I use MacTex 2021 on a macbook pro with TexStudio as editor (TeXstudio 3.1.2 (git 3.1.2)
Using Qt Version 5.15.2, compiled with Qt 5.15.2 R)

Comment: @AniruddhaGhosh - Thanks for providing this information. I will assume that you've updated MacTeX2021 on a regular basis. Incidentally, [MacTeX2022](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) was released a couple of months ago; you may want to look into updating your TeX distribution. (I happen to use MacTeX2022, along with TeXworks, which is distributed with MacTeX.) What happens if you (a)delete all aux files and (b) employ TeXworks instead of TeXstudio to compile the test document? The reason I ask is that TeXstudio is known to do an awful job at times reporting LaTeX error messages correctly.

Comment: I upgraded to MacTex 2022 and the code now works. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Redesign your table.

At least the first two column headings are too wide.

Remove the (OHM cm) from column headings and add it after Resistivity in the caption.  `\caption{Resistivity (OHM cm) of samples ...`

Plus other things that you might think of.

Answer (score 1):

People are good at scanning down a column of related numbers and seeing how it changes.  With that in mind, I would recommend stacking the resistance / sheet resistance / resistivity columns (and repeating volume and thickness as necessary).  That makes the table small enough, but we can do better.

Use siunitx to get microns and ohms (and not have to worry about the spacing for units).  Add units to all column headers.  Remove the table environment, and move the caption to the frame title (this means you can't refer to "Table 1" using the label, but you shouldn't refer to "Table 1" in a presentation anyway).  Add some `\cmidrule` to help with the stacked tables.  Use makecell to stack the two word column headers to make them narrower.

What is the purpose of the presentation?  22 numbers where 18 of them have 8-10 significant figures is pointless.  No one will be able to understand that.  I would recommend rounding your numbers to the nearest hundredth (or two significant figures, whichever is more).  This also gives enough room to use the siunitx column type `S`, which aligns your numbers on the decimal point (but you need to protect your column headings).  With a bit of spacing between the stacked tables, this becomes:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Resistivity of samples prepared from \SI[per-mode=fraction]{0.5}{\mg\per\ml} CNT solution}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cSSSS}
            \makecell{Volume\\(\si{\ml})} & {\makecell{Thickness\\(\si{\micro\m})}} & {\makecell{Resistance\\(\si{\ohm})}} & {\makecell{Sheet\\Resistance (\si{\ohm})}} & {\makecell{Resistivity\\(\si{\ohm\cm})}} \\\\
            & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{On cellulose filter} \\\cmidrule{3-5}
            10    & 3.02 & 16.33 & 73.97 & 0.022 \\
            20    & 6.84 & 7.25 & 32.83 & 0.022 \\\\
            & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{After transferring to glass substrate} \\\cmidrule{3-5}
            10    & 3.02 & 27.90 & 126.37 & 0.038 \\
            20    & 6.84 & 13.78 & 62.41 & 0.043 \\\\
            & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{After baking the transferred samples} \\\cmidrule{3-5}
            % these are repeated to give something to display
            10    & 3.02 & 27.90 & 126.37 & 0.038 \\
            20    & 6.84 & 13.78 & 62.41 & 0.043
        \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The `\si` and `\SI` macros are a bit deprecated; consider using `\unit` and `\qty` instead.

Comment: @Mico Those do seem a bit more intuitive to use.  Are those commands documented somewhere?  The current documentation on CTAN seems to be more focused on expl3 syntax commands.

Comment: `\unit` and `\qty` are both described in great detail starting on page 6 of the user guide of the `siunitx` package, v.3.1.1, dated 2022-05-03.

Comment: @Mico Ah.  I clicked on "Code Documentation", not "User Manual".  Sorry about that.